# Help in identifying elements used on LEGO Batman movie's Daleks

Tags: part-identification, moc

I've been working on making a replica of the Dalek from LEGO Batman.

I've worked my way through [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvNPNizWZe4) and the author identifies some differences between their (awesome) effort and the original from the film.

I've built a replica in the LDD and was trying to identify how the laser was constructed.

Currently the author is using a [64567 "Light sword shaft"](https://brickset.com/parts/design-64567) and [30374 Light sword blade](https://brickset.com/parts/design-30374), something like this...

[image: Blaster detail]

This is okay, but lacks some of the articulation which it should be capable of.  Now, I appreciate that the movie was CG based and some "cheating" probably took place, but I'd like to get as close as I can

From the movie...

[image: Unidentifiable part][image: More detail]

I've identified that the business end of the barrel is (indeed) a [64567 "Light sword shaft"](https://brickset.com/parts/design-64567), but I can't identify the shaft element which it is attached to (highlighted).

The 64567 part needs to attached to a 3.2 shaft part, but I can't identify the part which seems to have been used, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've spend some time going through the LDD catalog and brickset trying to identify it, without luck.

It "could" be [32828: Plate 1x1 Round W/ Horizontal 3.2 Shaft](https://brickset.com/parts/design-32828), but it doesn't seem to have the same reduction or node at the end. I've tried using a [92690 "0.2 Shaft w/ cored knob"](https://brickset.com/parts/design-92690) along with a [87994 "Shaft 3M 3.2"](https://brickset.com/parts/design-87994) to join the 64567 together, but it doesn't generate the same shape (and is generally to long)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like [Minifig, Utensil Tool Box Wrench - 3-Rib Handle
Item No: 11402i](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11402i&name=Minifig,%20Utensil%20Tool%20Box%20Wrench%20-%203-Rib%20Handle&category=%5BMinifig,%20Utensil%5D) (although it looks like the ribbing may have been omitted in the CGI model):

[image: piece image]

The socket end can clutch a stud, so it can be attached there.

This newer variant of this piece [has come in flat silver](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=11402i&in=S), which is probably the closest color so far if not *the* color, in 5 different sets so far.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, it's not in the LDD catalog . I'll need to some rework to flip the studs, but otherwise I think you're onto a winnder